# How can I make the line number field display numbers in hex?

Tags: visual-studio-code, hex, vscode-extensions

I am doing a side project where I need to type in the value to line numbers. It would be fine to just type it into a calculator, but that would be slow for many times. I tried digging around settings and google but found nothing so far. How can I make the line numbers be in hex, instead? Like line 1 be displayed as 01 and line 42 be displayed as 2a? If there is no extension already, how may I go about coding this?

Comment: I doubt that you can change the line numbers like that.  You could make an extension that decorates each line with its hex value though, so you could see it easily.

Comment: So it would have the number and hex value? Thats perfect. If it's extensions, what category would it fall under (aka which tutorial to follow) ?

Comment: I added an answer that is very simple, but still requires you to right-click on the line number to trigger a command that stores the hex value in the clipboard.  If this isn't what you are looking for, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be able to be done with a [text decorator](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/decorator-sample/src/extension.ts) - for an example.

Also it is very easy to set up an extension that gets the hex version of a line number by right-clicking the line number (and choosing a command).  Let me know if this works for you.

In your `package.json` you would have these `contributes`:

```json
"contributes": {
    "commands": [
        {
            "command": "folder-operations.getLineNumberHex",
            "title": "Copy the hex for this line number"
        }
       ],

    "menus": {
        "editor/lineNumber/context": [
            {
                    "command": "folder-operations.getLineNumberHex"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

using your own publisherID for the command.  And in your `extension.js` `activate` function you would have this command registration:

```js
let disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('folder-operations.getLineNumberHex', async (args) => {

    // args.lineNumber is 1-based
    const hexLineNumber = Number(args.lineNumber).toString(16);
    await vscode.env.clipboard.writeText(hexLineNumber);
});
```

Here it is working:

[image: get the line number as a hex from line number context menu]

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your effort.